# Float counted as zero when it isn't

Tags: objective-c, ios, c

In my game I have a header file that contains properties and functions for seasons in my game. These properties are all static and include a float representing the current season and another float representing the current point in the transition between seasons, being zero if it isn't transitioning.

Several functions throughout my game rely on the transition (two at this point) and one is working perfectly. Although, in another instance this isn't working at all.

In the class responsible for controlling the background for my game, when ever the "SeasonTransition" variable is referenced it just comes up zero. But in the other class, where the variable is referenced exactly the same way, it comes up with the real value.

This is a picture after a breakpoint has been called after the game could update a few frames:
[image]

Once again these variables are declared in a c header file:

```
#import "somestuff.h"

static float SeasonTransition
etc...
```

This shouldn't be doing this right? How could I fix this?

EDIT:

The Season.h file is as follows:

```
//GL.h contains different functions and global variables to be used anywhere in the project.
//This file, like Season.h is a singular header file with static declarations, and is setup
//the same way. I have been developing this from the start of the project and havent had any
//problems with it.
#import "GL.h"

static float currentSeason;

static float SeasonTransition;

static void UpdateSeason(){
    currentSeason += 0.0002f;

    float TransitionLength = 0.15f;
    float SeasonDepth = Clamp(currentSeason - floorf(currentSeason), 0, TransitionLength);
    float bigTL = TransitionLength / 4;
    float endTL = TransitionLength;
    float Speed2 = 0;
    float Speed1 = 1;
    float bRatio = SeasonDepth / bigTL;
    float eRatio = SeasonDepth / endTL;

    SeasonTransition = (SeasonDepth < TransitionLength) ?
    ((SeasonDepth < bigTL) ?
     (Speed1 * bRatio) + (Speed2 * (1.0f - bRatio)) :
     (Speed1 * (1.0f - eRatio)) + (Speed2 * eRatio))

    :

    Speed2;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the breakpoint stops the program before the line is executed?

Comment: Yes, but I continued through a couple times allowing it to be called a couple times first. The value of RaysRotation should be the value of the frame before, which was still more than zero. And if I go through again the value is still zero.

Comment: Just out of interest, can you print the sequence of "RaysRotation" variables without using the debugger. That will indicate whether it's a code problem (stays 0) or a debugger problem (changes). Also, are you using threads at all, or is this game single-threaded?

Comment: My game is single threaded. RaysRotation does change and hold a value if I do anything else to it, ie. RaysRotation -= 2, RaysRotation = 4. It is just variables inside Season.h it doesn't like. But any other class accepts it, where I do the exact same thing to get the variable. I have a line in a different class that reads: mult = SeasonTransition and it works perfectly.

Comment: Alex, if you are using SeasonTransition in another C file (despite stating earlier that you didn't), it's not the same one. Is that what you want, every C file having its own copy? If not, fix that first. Otherwise, show us the _actual_ definition of SeasonTranstion in the header file, including context. If possible, _all_ of season.h would be better - it may be the way you're defining it.

Comment: I have added the contents of Season.h

Comment: OMG! There's _code_ in there as well? :-) I have to ask one more time. Is that header file included or imported into more than one C file? If so, do you _want_ one copy of the variable (and code, now) for each C file? We need to sort that out before continuing.

Comment: I want ONE copy of each variable. It is currently used in 2 Objective-C classes, But it is only referenced twice in each class. It is first imported #import "Season.h", then the SeasonTransition variable is referenced. Out of the two classes, one of them gets the value, the other gets zero. The point of this is to have a globally accessible variable, so that any class in my game can figure out at what point the transition is at.

Comment: And, if these classes are separate files, go back an re-read my answer. You will have _two_ copies of the variable. The correct way to get _one_ copy is the `extern` method I suggested. Get all definition out of that header file (eg, static variables and code) and put them into C files. Only put declarations (eg, externs and prototypes) into header files. If you do that, your problems should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but I think the problem might be you don't quit understand how include/import work. These are not quit language features but preprocessor feature. When you include somewhere in a file, your say take the entire contents of that other file and stick it in here before your start compiling. So if you include the same header file in multiple different other files you will end up with multiple version of that static variable, with out the static you will get a compiler error because you have redefined the same variable multiple times. import works almost the same except if the preprocessor determines that the included file has already be include into the destination file (could be indirectly through another include), then it will not include the file again. If you understand this you can then see that declaring static variable within you header is quit strange, because you will end up with multiple versions of that variable everywhere that header is included. Normally you want to make the variable global in which case you define it in a .c or .m file and then declare it extern in the header or you want the variable to be private then you declare it static in the .c or .m file.

What static does is to hide the variable declaration from the linker, so the linker can not recognise that all the different declarations of the same name should be treated as the same variable.

Comment: I knew that include just inserted the contents of the file, but I didn't know that static variables are considered different. It makes sense though. Thanks! I changed my code to a Obj-C class that works as a dummy to return the static variables that are now stored in the .m file.

Answer (score 5):

If you put `static float SeasonTransition;` into two separate C files (or one header file *included* by two separate C files), each C file will have its own *independent* copy of the variable.

If one of those C files then modifies the variable, it will modify its copy. It will *not* touch the one in the other C file. That sounds like the situation you're in.

The normal way to do this is to define the variable in one and declare it external in the other, something like:

```
file1.c:
    int myVar;           // it exists here.

file2.c:
    extern int myVar;    // it exists, but elsewhere.
```

You don't want to mark it `static` in the first since that effectively makes it invisible to the second. And you mark it `extern` in the second so that it knows the variable exists elsewhere (in the first).

You would actually see the effect if it *weren't* static. When the linker came to link those two files together, it would complain about having *two* variables with the same name.

There are many variations on how to do that, I've shown the simplest. It's probably better to have something like:

```
file1.h:
    extern int myVar;   // so everyone knows about the variable
                        //   just by including this.
file1.c:
    #include "file1.h"  // or import for ObjC.
    int myVar;          // the actual variable.

file2.c:
    #include "file1.h"  // now we know about it, in the OTHER C file.
```

Comment: All of the variables and functions are static in the .h file alone. No file inherits from this header, therefore each variable exists once, and should be the same to everything referencing it. This is used quite a bit in my game, but this is the first time I ran into this problem.

Comment: @Alex, if no file "inherits from" (I presume you mean includes) the header then no C file knows about or defines the variable - that would cause a linker error with the code that tries to set it. Header files aren't compiled independently, they're included in other files. You need to clarify _exactly_ how that variable is declared and defined.

Comment: But my advice stands - you should generally _never_ define things in header files. By all means _declare_ them there, but the _definitions_ should be in regular C files so that they happen once and once only.

Comment: But I am doing this, it compiles without errors, and it DOES work in other classes. In a different class I simply import the header into my Obj-C class and call the variable and it works perfectly fine. But in this class I am doing it the exact same way, and is referencing the same global variable but it acts as zero in the equation. Look at my picture, the debugger window says that SeasonTransition has a value of non zero, but after a simple line that states RaysRotation = SeasonTransition, RaysRotation isn't being assigned with the value that the debugger plainly states

Comment: SeasonTransition has. Whether or not my approach to storing the variable is proper or not, there is something happening (or not happening) completely wrong.

Comment: @Alex if it's working in other **classes** do you mean headers that are referenced with `#import`? In that case, if I'm not mistaken, there will be only one copy of the variable, unlike with `#include`. I'm not 100% sure about that, I'll probably go check :)

Comment: @Alex, many things compile without errors yet are incorrect. That's why a distinction is made between syntax errors and runtime errors, or defined and undefined behaviour. Getting code to compile is only the _first_ step :-)

Comment: @Carl, import prevents multi-inclusion per compilation unit, it will not stop the same file from being included into two different compilation units, then linked together.

Comment: @Alex, how many C files do you actually _have_ in this project?

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef Season_h
#define Season_h

... your header stuff

#endif
```

Also, if you dont call updateSeason seasonTransition will be zero.